# How to split (& , and to) from a variable in python

Tags: python, split

I have a string like this

```
myString = "6003,333 to 2323 & sdsd"
```

How to split (& , and to) from above string in python

i tired this and i got this

```
>>> myString = "6003,333 to 2323 & sdsd"
>>> lastName = myString.split(',')
>>> print lastName
['6003', '333 to 2323 & sdsd']
```

Expected results

```
['6003', '333', '2323', 'sdsd']
```

can i use some thing like this split(',','&','to')???

Comment: `lastName = myString.split(',')[1].split('&')[1]`?

Answer (score 1):

```
myString = "6003,333 to 2323 & sdsd"
myString.replace("to", ",")
myString.replace("&", ",")

lastName = myString.split(',')
print lastName
```

Comment: Did you mean: `myString.replace("&", ",")`?

Answer (score 1):

use re.split()

```py
import re

myString = "6003,333 to 2323 & sdsd"
print(re.split(r',|&|to', ''.join(myString.split())))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"( to | & )", ",", myString).split(",")
['6003', '333', '2323', 'sdsd']
```

I think you can replace the `&` and `to` with `,`, and then split the string.

But I think @Hironsan's answer is better.